# Creating an iOS tableView using flexBox

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to create a grouped `UITableView` equivalent in a react-native app. Here's what it **should** look like:

[image]

I tried to create this by nesting different flex boxes together. Here's what it looked like (the red annotations are the flex boxes):

[image]

I've tried adding a `height` constraint, and played around with `justifyContent` and `alignItems` on the flex boxes and I was not able to change the way it looks. I need advice!

EDIT:

Here are the styles I'm using for this layout:

```
container: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  flex: 1
},
tableView: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#EFEFF4',
},
tableViewSection: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  flex: 1,
  paddingTop: 40,
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [react-tableview-simple](https://github.com/Purii/react-native-tableview-simple). You could also checkout the sources of this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a flex property on the child components, as long as you have declared a flex-direction: 'row' property on the parent.

I've recreated the design on [rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/wR2Idw).

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={styles.header}></View>
       <View style={styles.tableView}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>ACCOUNT</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subHeading}>Log Out</Text>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>COMPANY</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subHeading}>About</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subHeading}>Legal</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subHeading}>Rate on the App Store</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subHeading}>Server</Text>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1
  },
  tableView: {
    backgroundColor: '#EFEFF4',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  tableViewSection: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#0c65ab',
    height:60
  },
  heading: {
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingLeft:15,
    paddingBottom:10,
    fontSize:17,
    color: '#77777c',
  },
  subHeading: {
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingLeft:20,
    paddingBottom:20,
    fontSize:18,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Found out by guessing and testing other attributes of the flex box:

The `flex` property modifies the intrinsic content size of each element. The bigger the `flex`, the more expansive it is relative to the other items. To solve this dilemma, the top section needs a lower `flex` value of the bottom, so the space isn't distributed equally.

Change the `flex` value to 0 for the top section. This will cause the top section to collapse it's flex box to only surround it's immediate contents, while the lower flex box will expand to fill the rest of the space.